# Using Spring Security for Login with Spring MVC ,getting 404 error

Tags: spring-security, spring-4

I get the 404 error when I run my project in Tomcat 7.

**spring-security :**

```
<beans xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xsi:schemalocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security  
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">
    <!-- <beans:import resource="Employee-servlet.xml"/> -->

    <security:http use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/Springhib/index.jsp/" access="permitAll" />

        <intercept-url pattern="/Springhib/jsp/login.jsp"
            access="permitAll" />
        <form-login login-page="login.jsp" default-target-url="/welcome.jsp"
            authentication-failure-url="/error.jsp" />
        <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/logout.jsp" />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                users-by-username-query="select username,password enabled from userlogin where username= ?" />
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

**Employee-servlet.xml :**
It contains the dataSource(MySQL), hibernate transaction manager(Hibernate configuration) and internalviewresolver

**web.xml:**

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>SprinHib</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>

    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Employee</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Employee</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/Employee-servlet.xml,
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>

    </context-param>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <!--spring security -->
    <filter>

        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>

        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>

    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>

        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>

        <url-pattern>/**</url-pattern>

    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**project structure**

[image]

From index page I redirect to login page and at the same time in controller I instantiate a bean(POJO/Model)for further use in the next page.
On successful login user enter to welcome page.

**EDIT :**
**Index.jsp:**

```
<c:redirect url="login"/>
```

contains only an autoredirect .

I have searched through previous solutions in stackoverflow but didn't fix my issue.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show index.jsp. Also, there seems to be some path confusion (/SpringHib/jsp/... vs. /SpringHib/... vs. /)

Comment: I have edited to include index.jsp ,which has only an autoredirect to login page.

Comment: You are redirecting to "login" but there is nothing to handle that url.

Comment: Yes I have written the code in the controller :The login page name is login.jsp and I have written the internal view resolver in spring config xml.In a controller I have this code :@RequestMapping("/login") and method body has :new ModelAndView("login","ebean",ebean). Every thing was working fine until I implemented the Authentication(login) using spring security.Earlier I have written the code to connect to table and compare username and password using the query.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the idea behind sping-sec. You don't redirect to a login page. If an access to a secured URL is attempted and the current principal hasn't the authorization to access spring-sec will redirect to the login. Go, grab a book about spring-sec.

Comment: ok thanks for your valuable comments.